# Forms authentication "Remember me" does not remembering me

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm doing this:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName,
                                DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),
                                model.RememberMe, verification.UserId.ToString());
                            string hashedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

web.config:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="/" name="FunkyAuth" timeout="10000" />
  </authentication>
```

and I check it like that:

> protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   {
>
> ```
> HttpCookie formsCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
>
>         if (formsCookie != null)
>         {
>             FormsAuthenticationTicket auth = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsCookie.Value);
>
>             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auth.UserData)) return;
>
>             int userId = int.Parse(auth.UserData);
>
>             var principal = new FunkyPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(auth.Name), userId);
>
>             Context.User = principal;
>             Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
>
>             //Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] = formsCookie;
>         }
>     }
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Why it didn't persist it for long time?

Comment: Cookie is on its place! Both on local computer and on hosting server, but on local computer it works fine! At hosting computer it doesn't, why this could be?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the cookie is not being submitted to the server domain.